# Found package configuration file: C:/SFML/lib/cmake/SFML/SFMLConfig.cmake but it set SFML_FOUND to FALSE so package "SFML" is considered tobe NOTFOUND

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, mingw, sfml

I try to link SFML library to my project. I use the next:

1. gcc compiler
2. g++20
3. MinGW_w64 distro
4. OS: WIN

CMakeLists.txt

```
#--------------------------- MAIN CONFIGURATION ---------------------------#

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17.0)

project(black_penny)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fcoroutines -IC:/SFML/include")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static -static-libgcc")
set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE)

set(
MAIN_SRC
main.cpp
)

add_executable(
$CACHE{CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
${MAIN_SRC}
)

#----------------------------- LINK LIBRARIES -----------------------------#

# Adding Boost library;

find_package(Boost REQUIRED)

message(STATUS "Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message(STATUS "Boost_LIBRARIES: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
message(STATUS "Boost_VERSION: ${Boost_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "BOOST_SYSTEM: ${BOOST_SYSTEM}")
message(STATUS "BOOST_FILE_SYSTEM: ${BOOST_FILE_SYSTEM}")

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries($CACHE{CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} LINK_PUBLIC ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

# if windows compiler;

if(MINGW)
message(STATUS "MinGW compiler defined!")
SET(
WIN_LIBS
ws2_32
wsock32
)
target_link_libraries($CACHE{CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} ${WIN_LIBS})
endif()

add_subdirectory(tests)

# add SFML library;

set(SFML_DIR "C:/SFML/lib/cmake/SFML")
find_package(SFML REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)

if (SFML_FOUND)
message(STATUS "SFML was FOUND!")
#find_package(SFML REQUIRED graphics network audio window system)
#set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} sfml-graphics)
else()
message(STATUS "SFML was NOT FOUND")
endif()
```

CMake output:

```
-- Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: C:/MinGW/include
-- Boost_LIBRARIES:
-- Boost_VERSION: 1.81.0
-- BOOST_SYSTEM:
-- BOOST_FILE_SYSTEM:
-- MinGW compiler defined!
CMake Error at C:/SFML/lib/cmake/SFML/SFMLConfig.cmake:139 (message):
Requested SFML configuration (Static) was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:54 (find_package)

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:54 (find_package):
Found package configuration file:

    C:/SFML/lib/cmake/SFML/SFMLConfig.cmake

but it set SFML_FOUND to FALSE so package "SFML" is considered to be NOT
FOUND.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/Nikita/Documents/Project/Messanger/BlackPenny/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
make: \*\*\* \[Makefile:192: cmake_check_build_system\] Error 1
```

I try to download the ready SFML for win64, but it doesn't compile correctrly (don't find some libs mb. I have read that it isn't right build). So I compile sfml by my hands. Steps to compile I have found in the next video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJZRjcL4FCs&t=388s&ab_channel=AshishThapa